# Probability breakdown of a certain roll

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are **six** regular (6-sided) dice being rolled. However, each dice has **one** side colored **gold**. The 1st has a gold 1, the 2nd has a gold 2... and the 6th has a gold 6.

I calculate the probability of rolling two sets of three with 6 dice:

$$\frac{{6 \choose 2} {6 \choose 3} {3 \choose 3}}{6^6} = \frac{300}{6^6}$$

As there are ${6 \choose 2}$ ways to assign the numbers, ${6 \choose 3}$ ways to arrange the 1st set of 3 dice into the available spaces and ${3 \choose 3}$ for the 2nd set.

An example of this kind of roll would be `1 1 1 2 2 2` or `3 5 3 5 5 3` (i.e. two groups of 3 of a kind).

How can I determine how many of these 300 rolls have 0 gold sides, how many have 1 gold side, and how many have 2 gold sides.

For instance, the roll `2 1 2 1 2 1` would have 0 gold sides, the roll `1 1 1 2 2 2` would have 1 gold side (the 1st dice), and the roll `1 2 1 2 1 2` would have 2 gold sides (the 1st and 2nd dice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: "WLOG" means "Without Loss of Generality"

WLOG, the roll is 3-"1"'s and 3-"2"'s, sequenced as "111222".

WLOG, D-1 is the die with a gold "1", D-2 is the die with a gold "2".

Chance of D-1 being in the last 3 numbers times chance of D-2 **then** being in the first 3 numbers = chance of Gold = 0 ($G_0$)

$$G_0 = \frac{3}{6} \times \frac{3}{5}.$$

Chance of D-1 being in the first 3 numbers times chance of D-2 **then** being in the second 3 numbers = chance of Gold = 2 ($G_2$)

$$G_2 = \frac{3}{6} \times \frac{3}{5}.$$

Obviously,

$$G_1 = 1 - (G_0 + G_2).$$

$(G_x \times n) $ where $n$ is the number of throws gives the number of throws that produce exactly $x$ gold numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be $\displaystyle {4 \choose 2}{6 \choose 2}*2=180$.

You choose which 2 of the 6 numbers to be the gold faces. Then you choose which 2 of the 4 remaining numbers will be the first number (none of them possibly being a gold face), and the other two are left for the second number.

E.g.

1 x x 4 x x

1 1 x 4 x 1

1 1 4 4 4 1

Lastly, I think you may have made a mistake in your calculation. There are ${6 \choose 3}{6 \choose 2}*2=600$ ways to get three each of two numbers. You need to multiply by 2 because after you’ve selected the positions and the numbers, you can put the numbers in one way, or the opposite.

_ _ * _ * *

3,5

3 3 5 3 5 5

5 5 3 5 3 3

Comment: You should not multiply by $2$ as that would give you duplicates. When you choose $3$ out of $6$, the other $3$ automatically get taken by the other number. For example, if you choose first three, then the last three is the other number but $6C3$ also includes selections where you select last $3$. Then automatically the first $3$ are the other number.